# Choose a subsample of random numbers

Tags: r, random

I will play in the Brazilian Lottery with my friends. I requested every one of them to choose seven numbers. I create a variable for all of them.

```
pestana = c(04, 15, 29, 36, 54, 25, 07)
carol = c(7, 22, 30, 35, 44, 51, 57)
davi = c(8, 13, 21, 29, 37, 42, 55)
valerio = c(30, 20, 33, 14, 7, 41, 54)
victor = c(09, 11, 26, 33, 38, 52, 57)
```

Then, I created a list with all of the numbers, and a list with unique numbers (in order to avoid repeated numbers)

```
list = c(carol, davi, pestana, valerio, victor, diuli, cynara)
list2 = unique(list)
```

Finally, I made a sample() for the list2

```
sample(list2, 7)
```

After that, I was wondering. Is it possible for me not to use the unique and not have repeated numbers? Because for instance, that way, repeated numbers have the same probability of appearing, when in fact, they have more (for instance, seven appeared three times).

Answer (score 2):

How about this:

```r
pestana = c(04, 15, 29, 36, 54, 25, 07)
carol = c(7, 22, 30, 35, 44, 51, 57)
davi = c(8, 13, 21, 29, 37, 42, 55)
valerio = c(30, 20, 33, 14, 7, 41, 54)
victor = c(09, 11, 26, 33, 38, 52, 57)

list = c(carol, davi, pestana, valerio, victor)
l <- c(unlist(list))
nums <- table(l)
probs <- nums/sum(nums)

sample(names(probs), 7, prob = probs, replace=FALSE)
#> [1] "4"  "33" "44" "11" "29" "52" "8"
```

<sup>Created on 2022-12-14 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Using the `prob` argument, you can make some values more likely to show up than others.